# Exchanging BTC (bitcoin) for LTC (litecoin)

Tags: exchanges, litecoin

How can I safely exchange BTC for LTC? I've found a website called [Changelly](https://changelly.com/). Does anyone have any experience with this website? Are there other websites/ways to safely exchange cryptocurrency?

I want to make sure that if send BTC to a specific person, then they'll send me the corresponding amount of LTC.

Comment: Have used both Changelly and Shapeshift. I like Shapeshift best because of reasonable fees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use shapeshifter!

https://shapeshift.io/

No account needed, instant, and it has a fair exchange rate. I used it multiple times to exchange coins.